# Restrict GMSMapView to certain bounds

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have two coordinates, and I need to restrict my Google Maps map to the frame bounded by those two coordinates. For example, I have

```
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(
    coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 59.615440364671244, 
        longitude: -17.978949286043644
    ), coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 33.963318167747758, 
        longitude: 21.442294009029865
    )
)
```

Then, I write,

```
map.cameraTargetBounds = bounds
```

However, this does nothing to restrict the bounds of the map while it should. According to the documentation,

> If not nil, [cameraTargetBounds] constrains the camera target so that gestures cannot cause it to leave the specified bounds.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194769/how-do-i-prevent-gmsmapview-from-infinite-horizontal-scrolling) did not help me, partially because I must allow zooming as well as panning––it just must be restricted to a certain area.

Why is this not working, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **GoogleFletcher**. In this we will implement two filters (GMSCoordinateBound and Type). In start bound cordinate we will put current location and at end bound we will just add 1 in our current location cordinates.
Hopefully it helps.

```
let location = locations.last!
let neBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:location.coordinate.latitude,
                   longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
let swBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude + 1, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude + 1)
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: neBoundsCorner,coordinate: swBoundsCorner)
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .establishment 
    fetcher = GMSAutocompleteFetcher(bounds: bounds, filter: filter)
```