# How to prevent a GMSMapView from infinite scrolling with inertia?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, pan

[Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194769/how-do-i-prevent-gmsmapview-from-infinite-horizontal-scrolling) have been asked before but I want the restriction to work "smooth", e.g. when you have a horizontal and a vertical panning vector (e.g. you pan the map side and upwards), the map should not just stop at the first encounter of the restriction bounding box and stop all movements.

I imagine that you should be able to generously pan "inside" that bounding box and the inertia of all map panning should be kept. The component (lat/long) that hits a "barrier" should be bouncing back and the other component should scroll further until the scrolling momentum is finished.

How would I go about implementing such a function?

Comment: Try restricting the latitude and longitude of the map

Comment: How exactly? Could you give an example?

Comment: Change the coordinates here... 
let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.8683, longitude: 151.2086)
let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.994065, longitude: 151.251859)
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)

let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 50.0)
mapView.moveCamera(update)